# proving that formulas are theorems using deduction theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm working in $L_0$
I know I have to use the three axioms and inference rule. However, I'm finding it difficult to prove that $(\neg \alpha \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \beta))$ is a theorem. 
I find it very fiddly and unintuitive - as if I just have to sort of plug in random formulae and combine them to get what I need.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What is "$L_0$"? (As far as I know, that notation isn't common in general, even if that's what it's called in your class.)

Comment: $L[\{\neg \rightarrow\}]$ . Thanks

Comment: I have to wonder which textbooks students are reading that always lead them to think that the logic they are studying is the only logic.

Comment: I still don't know what that means. What exactly are your axioms and inference rule(s)? There are lots of different axiomatizations in $\neg$ and $\rightarrow$, you need to be specific.

Comment: I'm reading this as "not $\alpha$ implies ( $\alpha$ implies $\beta$)". If I'm reading this correctly I don't know how this could be true since we don't know anything about $\beta$

Comment: @furrane it is certainly true. To prove it, suppose $\neg\alpha $ we want to show $ \alpha\rightarrow\beta$, so suppose $\alpha $. Now we have a contradiction. Anything follows from a contradiction, and so, in particular $\beta $ does. Discharging your assumptions finishes the proof.

Comment: @DanielV Well, there does exist at least one way to talk about a unique set of axioms... or possibly a unique single axiom given that we have $\lnot$ and $\rightarrow$ as connectives and the letters for propositional variables appear in a certain order.  As far as I know, there exists *only* one shortest *currently* known ($\lnot$, $\rightarrow$) single axiom.  So, maybe these students are studying from the text that uses that axiom as the main system to study???  Of course, I'm joking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

1) $\vdash \lnot \alpha \to (\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha)$ --- Ax.1

2) $\lnot \alpha$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha$ --- from 1) and 2) by *modus ponens*

4) $\vdash (\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \beta)$ --- Ax.3

5) $\alpha \to \beta$ --- from 3) and 4) by *modus ponens*

> 6) $\lnot \alpha \to (\alpha \to \beta)$ --- from 2) and 6) by *Deduction Theorem*, discharging [a].

Comment: +1, although I believe the proof of the deduction theorem depends on which choice of LEM the axiom set uses.

Comment: @DanielV - NO; *Deduction Th* needs only Ax.1 : $α→(β→α)$ and Ax.2 : $((α→(β→\gamma)) \to ((α→β) \to (α→\gamma)))$.

Comment: Oh you are right.  I was momentarily confusing induction on each inference with induction on each axiom schema.  That makes this an even better answer.

Comment: @DanielV There is no law of the excluded middle (by which I mean either ApNp or ANpp) in a conditional-negation calculus.  Also, if Apq gets defined as CNpq, then ApNp is an abbreviation CNpNp, which is an instance of the law of identity Cpp.  ANpp is an abbreviation for CNNpp, so the law CApNpANpp says that CCNpNpCNNpp.  If Apq gets defined as CCpqq, then ApNp abbreviates CCpNpNp and ANpp abbreviates CCNppp.